# Extracting lines by iterating over a set of files in a PK zipped archive in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Being totally new to Haskell I thought that writing a small practical tool would be a good start for learning it. My goal is to implement some kind of a linux "more" command for displaying the content of a PK zipped archive file. So far I only managed to list the file names within the archive:

```
module Main where

import Codec.Archive.Zip
import Path
import Path.IO (resolveFile')
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as Byte (ByteString)

loadTicks :: Path Abs File -> EntrySelector -> IO Byte.ByteString
loadTicks ticksArchivePath entry = withArchive ticksArchivePath (getEntry entry)

extractEntries :: Path Abs File -> IO [EntrySelector]
extractEntries ticksArchivePath = withArchive ticksArchivePath loadEntries

loadEntries :: ZipArchive [EntrySelector]
loadEntries = fmap Map.keys getEntries

-- not really useful since only natural ordering is required
customSort :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering
customSort elem1 elem2 = compare elem1 elem2

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let ticksArchivePath = resolveFile' "data/data-small.zip" :: IO (Path Abs File)  
    let entries = extractEntries =<< ticksArchivePath :: IO [EntrySelector]  
    sortedEntries <- fmap (sortBy customSort) entries :: IO [EntrySelector]
    print sortedEntries
```

I am stuck at this point because I cannot figure out how to call the `loadTicks` function over each entry in `sortedEntries`. How can I do that in order to eventually obtain a `[String]` output that concatenates all lines from each file of the archive (example archive: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mp1TIPmJd74SGJ4Yy5J-BBsoyBPPPHRh) ?

*EDIT*

After @arrowd comments the following code works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Codec.Archive.Zip
import Path
import Path.IO (resolveFile')
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Text (takeEnd)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Prelude hiding (concat)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (concat)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as Byte (ByteString)

loadTicks :: Path Abs File -> EntrySelector -> IO Byte.ByteString
loadTicks ticksArchivePath entry = withArchive ticksArchivePath (getEntry entry)

extractEntries :: Path Abs File -> IO [EntrySelector]
extractEntries ticksArchivePath = withArchive ticksArchivePath loadEntries

loadEntries :: ZipArchive [EntrySelector]
loadEntries = fmap Map.keys getEntries

-- not really useful since only natural ordering is required
customSort :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering
customSort elem1 elem2 = compare elem1 elem2

isCSVFile :: EntrySelector -> Bool
isCSVFile entry = takeEnd 4 (getEntryName entry) == ".csv"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    ticksArchivePath <- resolveFile' "data/data-small.zip" :: IO (Path Abs File)
    entries <- extractEntries ticksArchivePath :: IO [EntrySelector]
    let sortedEntries = sortBy customSort entries :: [EntrySelector]
    let ticks = loadTicks ticksArchivePath
    contents <- mapM ticks sortedEntries :: IO [Byte.ByteString]
    print (concat contents)
```

Comment: `mapM (loadTicks ticksArchivePath) sortedEntries`

Comment: I tried something similar but I am getting the following error: "Couldn't match expected type ‘Path Abs File’ with actual type ‘IO (Path Abs File)’In the first argument of ‘loadTicks’, namely ‘ticksArchivePath’
  In the first argument of ‘mapM’, namely ‘(loadTicks ticksArchivePath)’
  In the expression: mapM (loadTicks ticksArchivePath) sortedEntries"

Comment: By adding an fmap (code edited) our suggestion works and I get an array of ByteString

Comment: You should write `ticksArchivePath <- resolveFile' ...` instead of `let ticksArchivePath = resolveFile' ...`. Think of `<-` as an operator that unwraps `IO`.

Comment: @arrowd I would like to grant you the answer points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take as a rule of thumb, that arrow `<-` "pulls" `a` from some `m a`, where `m` is a Monad. In this case, arrows of your do-block pull `a`s from `IO a`s.

So, to get rid of fmaps you should write

```
ticksArchivePath <- resolveFile' "data/data-small.zip" :: IO (Path Abs File)
```

instead of

```
let ticksArchivePath = resolveFile' "data/data-small.zip" :: IO (Path Abs File)
```

and

```
entries <- extractEntries ticksArchivePath :: IO [EntrySelector]
```

instead of

```
let entries = extractEntries =<< ticksArchivePath :: IO [EntrySelector]
```

Expressions starting with `let` in do-blocks are usually used for pure computations. In your case it is

```
let sortedEntries = sortBy customSort entries
```

StackOverflow documentation had a great section explaining monads and do-syntax, but alas, it is gone now.